# LocationManager GPS_PROVIDER taking too much time

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` to get the current location of the user but it's taking too much time to return the location, should I use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` over `GPS_PROVIDER` ? Or there is something new and better to get the current location of the user to trace a destination route ?.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, object : LocationListener{...}
```

Comment: there is https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/ you should use it.

Comment: GPS hardly works indoors and having a SIM card in the device probably helps due to A-GPS. The NETWORK_PROVIDER isn't very accurate, but may be enough in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use fused location provider. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates).

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look

Comment: Good for first load, managing callbacks or implementing Single Update is a mess with Location API.

Answer (score 0):

Using the GPS_PROVIDER does take a little while to fetch location updates probably because of its accuracy in my opinion. You could also instead of wanting a new location request an older location that's slightly stale (Say for example 2 mins old) and that would be almost ready to use.

I would, however, recommend NOT using Location Manager at all and since it is depreciated and was replaced by a much cleaner and performant [Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider). It has support for last location, location updates and it's the currently the method Google recommends.